# SQL Need to remove duplicate items from a Union

Tags: sql, t-sql, duplicates, union

I have a query that I'm writing.  It collects some data from a few different tables and also runs a sum and some averages.
Initially, my customer asked me to select based on certain criteria, limiting from the overall list of parts, however, now the customer wants to be able to show all items even if they don't fall into the criteria.
The issue I'm having is that my initial query obviously limits the selection because it needs to use the where clause to decide certain criteria (for instance, based on a category, it includes results only when they are negative but not when positive) and in attempting to use a union, I get a duplicate entry any time something does fall into the criteria.  Meaning, my second Select gets everything, but it is not filtering out that entry when it was already added from the first.  Union does not regard these are distinct, as the calculated fields are different, even though the part number is matching.

I tried to make an inverse set of Where conditions that will simply get the mirror image of the initial selection, thus removing any potential for duplication, however, I cannot find the right criteria.

Can I either have help making an opposite selection for the following set of Where conditions (the two division parameters need to be the same for both, but creating an inverse set of conditions for the others may work, I just can't figure out how):

```
WHERE(iitt.Name = 'Invoicing'
      OR iitt.Name = 'Issuing'
      OR (iitt.Name = 'Post Worksheet'
          AND iit.quantity <= 0))
     AND iit.TransactionDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
     AND id.DivisionFK = @division
     AND iit.DivisionNumber = @division
```

Or else some method to select distinctly based on a match in just a certain field among a union, rather than an identical match for every field being the only criteria that union filters results by?  Select Distinct or Top 1 does not work.  The complete code is below:

```
DECLARE @startdate DATE, @enddate DATE, @division INT;
SET @startdate = '5/23/2018';
SET @enddate = '6/26/2018';
SET @division = 2;
SELECT i.PartNumber AS 'Part Number',
       CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, CAST(ABS(SUM(iit.quantity)) AS DECIMAL(19, 0))) AS 'Sum Quantity',
       CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, id.quantityOnHand) AS 'Division Quantity on Hand',
       CASE
           WHEN SUM(iit.quantity) = 0
           THEN 0
           WHEN DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @enddate) - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @startdate) = 0
           THEN 0
           WHEN YEAR(@enddate) - YEAR(@startdate) = 1
           THEN CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, CAST(ABS((SUM(iit.quantity) / ((364 - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @startdate)) + DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @enddate)))) AS DECIMAL(19, 2)))
           WHEN YEAR(@enddate) - YEAR(@startdate) = 2
           THEN CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, CAST(ABS(SUM(iit.quantity) / ((364 - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @startdate)) + DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @enddate) + 364)) AS DECIMAL(19, 2)))
           ELSE CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, CAST(ABS(SUM(iit.quantity) / (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @enddate) - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @startdate))) AS DECIMAL(19, 2)))
       END AS 'Avg Use Per Day',
       CASE
           WHEN SUM(iit.quantity) = 0
           THEN NULL
           WHEN SUM(iit.quantity) / ((364 - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @startdate)) + DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @enddate)) = 0
           THEN 0
           WHEN SUM(iit.quantity) / ((364 - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @startdate)) + DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @enddate) + 364) = 0
           THEN 0
           WHEN SUM(iit.quantity) / ((364 - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @startdate)) + DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @enddate) + 364) = 0
           THEN 0
           WHEN SUM(iit.quantity) / (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @enddate) - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @startdate)) = 0
           THEN 0
           WHEN YEAR(@enddate) - YEAR(@startdate) = 1
           THEN CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, CAST(ABS(ROUND(id.quantityOnHand / ((SUM(iit.quantity) / ((364 - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @startdate)) + DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @enddate)))), 2)) AS DECIMAL(19, 2)))
           WHEN YEAR(@enddate) - YEAR(@startdate) = 2
           THEN CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, CAST(ABS(ROUND(id.quantityOnHand / (SUM(iit.quantity) / ((364 - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @startdate)) + DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @enddate) + 364)), 2)) AS DECIMAL(19, 2)))
           ELSE CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, CAST(ABS(ROUND(id.quantityOnHand / (SUM(iit.quantity) / (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @enddate) - DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @startdate))), 2)) AS DECIMAL(19, 2)))
       END AS 'Depletion Days per Avg Use',
       CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, CAST(ROUND(ii.StandardCost, 3) AS DECIMAL(19, 3))) AS 'Standard Cost'
FROM Item i
     INNER JOIN ItemInventoryTransaction iit ON i.itempk = iit.itemfk
     INNER JOIN ItemInventoryTransactionType iitt ON iitt.ItemInventoryTransactionTypePK = iit.ItemInventoryTransactionTypeFK
     INNER JOIN ItemInventory ii ON i.ItemInventoryFK = ii.ItemInventoryPK
     INNER JOIN ItemDivision id ON i.ItemPK = id.ItemFK
     INNER JOIN Division d ON id.DivisionFK = d.DivisionPK
WHERE(iitt.Name = 'Invoicing'
      OR iitt.Name = 'Issuing'
      OR (iitt.Name = 'Post Worksheet' AND iit.quantity <= 0))
     AND iit.TransactionDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
     AND id.DivisionFK = @division
     AND iit.DivisionNumber = @division
GROUP BY i.PartNumber,
         id.quantityOnHand,
         ii.StandardCost
UNION
SELECT i.PartNumber AS 'Part Number',
       NULL AS 'Sum Quantity',
       CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, id.quantityOnHand) AS 'Division Quantity on Hand',
       NULL AS 'Avg Use Per Day',
       NULL AS 'Depletion Days per Avg Use',
       CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, CAST(ROUND(ii.StandardCost, 3) AS DECIMAL(19, 3))) AS 'Standard Cost'
FROM Item i
     INNER JOIN ItemInventoryTransaction iit ON i.itempk = iit.itemfk
     INNER JOIN ItemInventoryTransactionType iitt ON iitt.ItemInventoryTransactionTypePK = iit.ItemInventoryTransactionTypeFK
     INNER JOIN ItemInventory ii ON i.ItemInventoryFK = ii.ItemInventoryPK
     INNER JOIN ItemDivision id ON i.ItemPK = id.ItemFK
     INNER JOIN Division d ON id.DivisionFK = d.DivisionPK
WHERE id.DivisionFK = @division
      AND iit.DivisionNumber = @division
ORDER BY [Part Number];
```

Comment: By default `UNION` means `UNION DISTINCT`, so it should remove duplicates all by itself. But all the columns have to be the same, otherwise they're not really duplicates.

Comment: See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for how to invert combinations of `AND` and `OR` conditions.

Comment: Isn't inverting a condition as simple as `WHERE NOT (condition)` ?

Comment: I found a way.  First, make the union'd select a With, and then select the max for each value and it will cut out the duplicate rows.

    With Usage As (
    ...
         )
         SELECT MAX([part number]),
                MAX([Sum Quantity]),
                MAX([Division Quantity on Hand]),
                MAX([Avg Use Per Day]),
                MAX([Depletion Days per Avg Use]),
                MAX([Standard Cost])
         FROM Usage
         GROUP BY [part number];

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is to add WHERE clauses to your second query that invert what your first query filters, thus avoiding duplicates from the word go.

I caution against using aggregate expressions like MAX in everything, since that opens you up for data inconsistency if any of the two duplicate entries are ever not the same for any fields you select, and it's also slower for no reason and less legible.

Example for the WHERE to be added to your second query of the union:

```
WHERE(iitt.Name <> 'Invoicing'
      AND iitt.Name <> 'Issuing'
      AND (iitt.Name <> 'Post Worksheet'
          OR iit.quantity > 0))
     OR iit.TransactionDate NOT BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
     OR id.DivisionFK <> @division
     OR iit.DivisionNumber <> @division
```

This is with your above conditionals inverted based on the [De-Morgan Laws of Binary Math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)